# TableLayoutPanel Spacing Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I adding labels to a tablelayoutpanel from an array.  The labels add no problem, but their is a huge gap between each of the labels.  Did I code something incorrectly?  This is my array, and adding the labels.  The tablelayoutpanel is added from the GUI and is named tablelayoutpanel1

```
while (dr.Read())
{
labelsToAdd.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}
dr.Close();
foreach (string label in labelsToAdd)
{
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Name = "lbl_" + index;
lbl.Text = label;
lbl.AutoSize = true;
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, rowIndex);
rowIndex++;
}
```

So they will add like this with all the whitespace in between them

```
label1





label2
```

Visual Sample -
[image]

Comment: Add a visual example as well

Comment: How are you adding the rows to the TableLayoutPanel control?  Are the rows set for AutoSize?

Comment: Their is 1 row and 2 columns.  They were added by dragging & dropping the control from the toolbox.

Comment: If there is only one row, then how are you adding multiple labels to each row?  How did you get the number of rows in your reader to match-up with the number of rows in your TableLayoutControl?

Comment: @LarsTech I was using the above syntax and it adds all the elements of the array, just with crazy spacing involved.  I take it that is not the proper way to do such?

Comment: Are all of the rows like that?  Or just the first row or two?

Comment: @LarsTech only the 1st two display like that.  The rest display as desired.

Comment: This is an old question, but I just ran into the same problem.  It turns out that if you add rows to the TableLayoutPanel using the form builder in Visual Studio, and then later remove those rows using the designer (in my case to build the table dynamically), it removes all of the controls that were in the panel, but leaves all of the calls to RowStyles.Add in the designer class.  These have to be removed manually.  The answer below also fixed it by removing all of the rowstyles that were added by the designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment:

> only the 1st two display like that. The rest display as desired.

So it looks like you should clear the rows first since your `GrowStyle = AddRows`:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
foreach (string label in labelsToAdd)
{
  Label lbl = new Label();
  // etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the row height:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30))
```

Comment: Not following you...if I go to my designer.cs file and try to add this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Height = 30 it tells me Height is not valid.

Comment: @user2676140 **Never** edit the designer file where it says "do not modify".

Comment: How about by Absolute SizeType ?

Comment: @MikeG I am only using one row.  And doing SizeType.Absolute, 30 does not remedy either.